# Avoid to reload a background at every frame in pygames

Tags: python, pygame

I want to make a game using pygames in python and I have a background which I want to load only at the beginning of the game not at every frame and the background should still appear.
I load the background like this in a init function:

```
self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((self.SCREEN_WIDTH, self.SCREEN_HEIGHT))
self.screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
self.rasp = "../images/image.jpg"
self.rasp_surface = pygame.image.load(self.rasp)
self.rasp_surface = pygame.transform.scale(self.rasp_surface, (self.SCREEN_WIDTH, self.SCREEN_HEIGHT))
self.screen.blit(self.rasp_surface, (0,0))
```

and in a run function I do this :

```
while True:
    ...
    self.screen.blit(self.rasp_surface, (0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a while loop with pygame.display.update() in it, you are constantly doing this. This is unnecessary. However, it is likely you are moving sprites or images over the background, so just make sure to fill in the portion of the image that the sprite is moving over as it moves. You can make a move function to do that for you.